# How do I design a .NET (C#) for a program that needs to run as a Windows service but also have a web interface?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, windows-services

I am designing a piece of software that needs to operate different pieces of hardware based mainly on a schedule but it also needs to have a web interface for configuring settings, configuring the schedule, and possibly even manually controlling the hardware.  I'm not sure how to design the architecture of software like this.

One thought that I have had was to create a Windows service that does the communication with the hardware as well as "publishing" web services through WCF and then having an ASP.NET application that then controls the Windows service through WCF.  This approach seems to be a lot of work for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Could someone please give me some direction whether or not this is a good approach, and even give me a better way to do it if one exists?

Thanks!
Joel

Comment: For security reasons the best solution will depend a lot on your hardware configuration. How does the machinery accept requests? Where will your web site reside with respect to your windows service? What firewalls are involved? Can you instead run a Windows service that polls a web service and has a UI as well?

Comment: The machinery primarily accepts requests via one or more serial ports (RS485 networks).  Website could be on the same machine as the service, but I like the ability to have them split up if necessary.  Firewall's probably won't be an issue in this case as it'll all be on the same network.  Can you explain what you mean be a "Windows service that polls a web service and has a UI as well?"  I'm not sure how a Windows service could have a UI.

Comment: If you want to host the web interface on a different machine, there is no alternative to your thought.

Comment: "I'm not sure how a Windows service could have a UI." Well, it shouldn't, to be fair. Better to have a separate UI app that uses RPC to talk to the service. But what I really meant is having a web service and web site that both connect direct to the machine. Then on a control PC, have a windows service that polls the web service while a user can connect via a browser to the web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate a WCF endpoint as a TCP service from within the Windows service, as explained on MSDN: [How to: Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949080.aspx) .

From there, it is relatively straightforward to consume that endpoint in an ASP.NET application (same as consuming any other WCF endpoint).

In the absence of any compelling reasons to do otherwise, this is probably the approach I would take.  Your only other option is to use some other form of IPC, such as memory-mapped files or named pipes.  WCF is a lot easier to get up and running.

Comment: This is the solution I was coming to.  However, I didn't now about embedding ASP.Net web server into a service.  If that requires me to still use WCF for communication, then this may still be the way to go.

Comment: My followup question in regard to WCF is: Would it be fast enough for being an intermediary between the web UI and the hardware?  I don't think I can be waiting multiple seconds for WCF responses.

Comment: @hjoelr: WCF is very fast, even when you have encryption and other extensions turned on. I'm accustomed to response times on the order of about 1/4 of a second from remote servers; normally the only delay is due to network latency, and if you have all services running on the same machine or at least the same network then latency should be almost nil.

Comment: @Aaronaught: That is very reassuring!  Thanks for the info on WCF speed.

Comment: The only concern here is security. IIS offers a lot of features that you may have to replicate; if not at first then perhaps when you want to extend the architecture. Better to try to host web services in IIS (which has been tested for security, found wanting, fixed and retested many times) than in a service, if possible.

Comment: @pdr: I'm not really sure what you mean by "security" here; WCF uses the same message-level security (with optional authentication, encryption, etc.) whether you run it over a TCP binding or HTTP.  It doesn't even really use much of the ASP.NET stack when you run it under ASP.NET.  The only thing you don't get for free is transport security (SSL), which you don't need if you enable message security. Hosting WCF over TCP isn't like hand-rolling your own TCP service; there's already a hosting API, you just have to change a few bindings.

Comment: In fact, that was one of the primary aims of WCF - to be able to host it anywhere, in any form.  You can even hook it up to MSMQ.  There's really no significant security risk to using the TCP bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a common XML file (or something) that the service monitors for changes. The web interface could just read/write that XML file. This only works well if the service and web site are running on the same machine (you can do it through a share as well, but that's extra configuration and you may was well just go with WCF in that case).

Comment: Good thought.  However, there needs to be two-way communication.  The website polls information from the service but the website must also be able to update settings and such in the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed an ASP.Net web server in the service using the ASP.Net hosting API, then use it to run an ASP.Net website directly.

Note that the ASP.Net site would run in a separate AppDomain.

Comment: You still have to develop the ASP.NET site separately though.  This doesn't really preclude the need to come up with a means of communication between the ASP.NET app and the service, it just allows you to run the whole package without IIS.

Comment: @Aaronaught: You can simply pass a `MarshalByRefObject` that exposes the service to `ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost` and interact with it in ASP.Net. (The ASP.Net project should reference the service assembly)

Comment: This is an interesting concept.  I didn't know this was even possible.  I'll see if I can look into this to see if it would work for my situation.

Comment: True about `MarshalByRefObject` - although once you start getting into remoting then (IMO) it's easier to go with WCF.  You're right, though, this can technically be done without any of the traditional IPC methods.